# Google Cloud Committed Use

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Are these transferable between projects?  Is there a way?

We had a client shut down and we have a year left on the committed use discount.  Can we roll it to another project in the same Google Cloud account?

Answer (score 0):

[The short answer is no](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/signing-up-committed-use-discounts#canceling_a_commitment). I recommend contacting the [Google Cloud Platform billing team](https://cloud.google.com/support/billing/#contact_support) to see if an exception can be made in your specific case.

Answer (score 0):

As this question was asked 4 years ago, the answer might be different for today. The answer today would be:

It depends on the CUD you've chosen.

> By default, committed use discounts apply at the project level, but you can enable discount sharing from your billing account to share discounts across multiple projects.

Source: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/signing-up-committed-use-discounts